# ActiveRecord Calculate the Sum of Columns and Group them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following query

```
engagement_metrics = EngagementMetric.where(engagement_id: engagement_ids).order('metrics_date desc').limit(7).group_by { |p| p.metrics_date }
```

which results in something like this

```
{
    "2016-05-13": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "provider": "facebook",
            "likes": -2,
            "comments": 0,
            "shares": 0,
            "views": 0,
            "reach": 0,
            "reactions": {
                "sad_count": "0",
                "wow_count": "-1",
                "haha_count": "0",
                "like_count": "-1",
                "love_count": "0",
                "angry_count": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "provider": "facebook",
            "likes": 2,
            "comments": 2,
            "shares": 2,
            "views": 2,
            "reach": 0,
            "reactions": {
                "sad_count": "0",
                "wow_count": "0",
                "haha_count": "0",
                "like_count": "0",
                "love_count": "0",
                "angry_count": "0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "2016-05-12": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "provider": "facebook",
            "likes": 1,
            "comments": 3,
            "shares": 0,
            "views": 0,
            "reach": 0,
            "reactions": {
                "sad_count": "1",
                "wow_count": "0",
                "haha_count": "0",
                "like_count": "0",
                "love_count": "0",
                "angry_count": "0"
            },
            "engagement_id": 1,
            "participation_id": 1,
            "campaign_id": 1,
            "influencer_authorization_id": 1,
            "influencer_id": 1,
            "social_account_id": 1,
            "metrics_date": "2016-05-12",
            "status": "processed",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "created_at": "2016-05-14T11:36:55.995Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-05-14T11:36:55.995Z"
        }
    ],
    "2016-05-11": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "provider": "facebook",
            "likes": 0,
            "comments": 16,
            "shares": 0,
            "views": 0,
            "reach": 0,
            "reactions": {
                "sad_count": "0",
                "wow_count": "0",
                "haha_count": "0",
                "like_count": "0",
                "love_count": "0",
                "angry_count": "0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "2016-05-10": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "provider": "facebook",
            "likes": 3,
            "comments": 4,
            "shares": 0,
            "views": 0,
            "reach": 0,
            "reactions": {
                "sad_count": "0",
                "wow_count": "1",
                "haha_count": "0",
                "like_count": "1",
                "love_count": "1",
                "angry_count": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Which is the best way to iterate through to get data like below

```
[
    {
        "date": "24/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "29",
            "comments_count": "456",
            "shares_count": "234",
            "views_count": "65",
            "clicks_count": "123"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "25/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "345",
            "comments_count": "234",
            "shares_count": "876",
            "views_count": "345",
            "clicks_count": "45"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "26/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "345",
            "comments_count": "265",
            "shares_count": "243",
            "views_count": "165",
            "clicks_count": "87"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "27/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "376",
            "comments_count": "87",
            "shares_count": "54",
            "views_count": "754",
            "clicks_count": "34"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "28/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "103",
            "comments_count": "324",
            "shares_count": "405",
            "views_count": "87",
            "clicks_count": "354"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "29/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "23",
            "comments_count": "65",
            "shares_count": "234",
            "views_count": "87",
            "clicks_count": "34"
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "30/03/16",
        "metrics": {
            "likes_count": "98",
            "comments_count": "576",
            "shares_count": "34",
            "views_count": "365",
            "clicks_count": "212"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try your best to group in the DB (using `group`) instead of ruby code (`group_by`) for performance reasons. I think that what you requested, i.e. *daily sums of the given columns*, can be retrieved using custom selects and grouping:

```
EngagementMetric.
    select("metrics_date as date").
    select("sum(likes) as likes_count").
    select("sum(comments) as comments_count").
    select("sum(shares) as shares_count").
    select("sum(views) as views_count").
    select("sum(clicks) as clicks_count").
    where(engagement_id: engagement_ids).        
    group("date").
    order("date desc").
    to_json

 # => [{ date: "2016-05-01", likes_count: 123, comments_count: 456, ... }, {...}]
```

I.e. this will sum all the data in daily groups and return the results. You just need to construct a little different JSON now if you want your metrics sums to .appear under a "metrics" subkey (which can be done using a [custom `as_json` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)).

Comment: wow that significantly increased the performance. could you share any links where i can learn how more about writing advanced queries like these.

Comment: Glad that it worked for you and sorry I don't know many tutorial sources about SQL, but [this](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlgroupby.html) online tutorial looks good to me.